# Connect to a Bluetooth Classic (Not LE) device on iOS, without using the External Accessory Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, external-accessory, mfi

Is there a way to establish a connection from a bluetooth classic device (not LE), to an iPhone, for data exchange?

The device we are using has a bluetooth classic chip, therefore it is not possible for us to use the Core Bluetooth Framework to make the connection since Core Bluetooth supports only Bluetooth LE.

I would like to connect our device using the Hands Free Profile or the HID Profile. How would we do this in the iOS Code? What frameworks or APIs are to be used?

The external accessory framework supports only MFi compliant devices. Do we have to be a part of the MFi Program? Or is it possible to establish the connection in some other way, something that I may be missing out?

Also, jailbreaking is not an option since we wish to release the app to a larger user base while selling our hardware device. We want to enable the users to make a connection through the app to their device.

Comment: To connect to a legacy Bluetooth device you will need to join the MFi program and get your device MFi certified.  You can send/receive audio data using the Hands Free Profile or receive keyboard input using the HID profile without MFi certification

Comment: Can you give me more details on how to do that with respect to developing our app?

Comment: Not really. Unless you want to send/receive audio data you don't have much option; you need to use BLE or enroll in the MFi program

Comment: But you just said in your comment above, "You can send/receive audio data using the Hands Free Profile or receive keyboard input using the HID profile without MFi certification."

Comment: That's right. Is your device a handsfree device or a keyboard?

Comment: Not really. But exchange of audio data and input is a major part of what we need. Maybe there is some workaround we could do to satisfy our requirement. What would the procedure to implement this exchange through our app? Are there any specific APIs I could use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121171/discussion-between-paulw11-and-anmol-mahatpurkar).